# Wrap variable words in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on a variety of user inputs, we put an array of words in a hidden div (#words) and then perform functions using that info.

What I would like to do is check the div for the existing words, i.e.:

```
terms = $("#words").html();
```

And then, in a visible and separate div elsewhere on the page (.ocrText), wrap only those words in a strong tag.

```
$('.ocrText').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/term/g, "<strong>term</strong>"));
});
```

So, if they'd searched for "Tallant France" and we stored that, then the following sentence:

"Mark Tallant served in France."

Would become:

"Mark `<strong>`Tallant`</strong>` served in `<strong>France</strong>`."

But I don't know how to inject that variable in to .replace()

///

EDIT: The terms are inserted in to the #words div in this format:
["Tallant","France","War"] ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ocrText').each(function() {
    var term = 'term'
    var pattern = RegExp(term, 'g')
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(pattern, "<strong>" + term + "</strong>"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your words contain only alphnumeric characters you can construct a single regexp to search of all of them at once as follows:

```
html = html.replace (
  new RegExp(terms.split(/\s*,\s*|\s+/).join('|'), 'g'), '<strong>$&</strong>');
```

The split should convert the terms string into an array containing the individual words, in the example I have coded it to split on commas optionally surround by whitespace or just whitespace.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working. The terms are inserted in to the #words div in this format: ["Tallant","France","War"] ... and so on.

Comment: OK, this is compatible with the JSON format, use "JSON.parse (terms)" in place of "terms.split(...)"